# Including SUBs While .SAVEAS

Tags: excel, vba

I'm converting CSVs to XLSMs using a new temporary file with the following SUB.

```
sub a()
j=array("apple","orange")
for each i in j
workbooks.open environ("userprofile") & "\desktop\" & i & ".csv"
activeworkbook.saveas environ("userprofile") & "\desktop\" & i & ".xlsm", xlopenxmlworkbookmacroenabled
activeworkbook.close
next i
end sub
```

I wonder whether I can include this SUB to each of the new XLSMs. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to enable programmatic access to the VBIDE object model, and then use it to programmatically add a module to the workbook's `VBProject.VBComponents`. Note that you should probably declare a local `wb As Workbook` variable, and do `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...)`, and then `wb.SaveAs` and `wb.Close`

Comment: Not sure which sub you want in the new workbooks, but a neat approach to this kind of issue is to have the desired sub in a "master workbook", open that workbook, transfer contents of the csv to that workbook, save the master workbook with a different name, close the csv, and now you have both the contents of the csv and also all the subs in the master workbook. Since you would be using Workbook.SaveAs, the master workbook would be retained to work with later. There was a post about this in SO to which I don't have the link to currently. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It seems I need to consider the "master workbook" approach instead.